# Microsoft Visual Studio SQL Database C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to update a table in my database whenever a button is pressed. I want to be able to update a certain column based on the radio button that is checked and a certain row of the name in the text box matches a name in the table. Does anyone have suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: welcome to stack...this seems like your assignment for the day..consider adding what you have done so far..stack is about getting help on your unsolved problems and not code sourcing community..

Comment: See [how to ask as question here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Sorry I added this on the run from my phone while I'm out doing stuff because I forgot to ask the question last night. This is why I haven't attached any code that I have tried. Will add when I get back, but it was along the lines of what the answer below is. Think I may have forgot to add a line or so compared to what they have though

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a SQL Server database, I would use a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand` object with an `UPDATE` command (`conn` in the following is a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE MY_TABLE SET VALUE = @Value WHERE NAME = @Name", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Value", /* checked button value */);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", /* row name */ );

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily update your table using Entity Framework also.

```
using (var db = new MyContextDB())
{
    var book = db.Books.SingleOrDefault(b => b.BookName == textBox1.Text);
    if (book != null)
    {
        try
        {
            book.IsAvailableOnline = radioButton1.Checked;
            db.Entry(book).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```